# Declaring BASH. Array of strings in a a script

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm writing a small script to test my regex understanding of comparison operator "=~". I thought that my syntax was alright but I keep getting:

3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

this is my small script link to this syntax error :

```
#!/bin/bash

inputsArr=("ab" "67" "7b7" "g" "67777" "07x7g7" "77777" "7777" "")

for input in ${inputsArr[@]}; do
  if [[ "$1" =~ "$input" ]]; then
    echo "$?"
fi
done
```

I try to compare in a loop with an array some "strings" against my arg1 or "$1"

Comment: That looks somewhat (though not exactly) like the error you would get if you ran the script with `dash` instead of `bash`.

Comment: Btw.: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I suspect that you are not calling the script with `./your_script.sh` but with `sh your_script.sh`. On ths way you use `sh` and not `bash`. `sh` does not know arrays.  See: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Side note: you should double-quote `${inputsArr[@]}` as well as regular variable references, to prevent the shell from mangling the array elements (via word splitting and filename wildcard expansion). On the other hand, if `$input` is supposed to be treated as a regular expression rather than a fixed string, you should remove the double-quotes around it (note: this is specific to how the right-hand side of a `[[ =~ ]]` comparison works). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works in bash, you just need to run it in the right shell, you can do the following:

```
  bash ./script.sh g
```

Also type `ps -p $$` (not `echo $SHELL`) to see what shell you are currently in:

Examples:

```
# ps -p $$
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  25583 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
# exit
# ps -p $$
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  22538 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
```

- $SHELL is to tell you what the current user has but you can change on the fly so that is why the other command is more useful.
- Borne shell (sh) does not play as nicely with arrays. You have to use eval.
- change your default shell to bash. Ref: https://www.tecmint.com/change-a-users-default-shell-in-linux/

Comment: The Bourne shell doesn't do arrays at all; you can sort-of fake them with `eval`, but unless you know exactly what you're doing and are very careful, it tends to be weirdly buggy. If you need arrays, it's much better to use a shell that actually supports them, like bash, zsh, or ksh.

Answer (score 0):

I just reach my goal with this !

```
#!/bin/bash

inputsArr=("ab" "67" "7b7" "g" "67777" "07x7g7" "77777" "7777" "")

for input in ${inputsArr[@]}; do [[ "$input" =~ $1 ]]; echo "$?" ; done
```

I would like to say thanks you to every person that give me some tips on this basic BASH script problem. Without you I would certainly not reach my goal by my own way and it is beautiful to see this cooperation in action.